# Tap on display objects in Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk, event-listener, tap

I'm trying to print taps from 3 different display objects but more than the one tapped are printed in the Terminal. 
They need their own specific function but that's not possible as of now. What should I do?
I am new to Corona and LUA.

> > > > -- BOBLER DISPLAY OBJEKTER
> > > >
> > > > local sport1 = display.newImage("images/sport1.png")
> > > >
> > > > sport1.id = "mySport1"
> > > >
> > > > sport1.x = 120
> > > >
> > > > sport1.y = 90
> > > >
> > > > sport1:scale(1,1)
> > > >
> > > > local gossip1 = display.newImage("images/gossip1.png")
> > > >
> > > > gossip1.id = "myGossip1"
> > > >
> > > > gossip1.x = 400
> > > >
> > > > gossip1.y = 120
> > > >
> > > > gossip1:scale(1,1)
> > > >
> > > > local kultur1 = display.newImage("images/kultur1.png")
> > > >
> > > > kultur1.id = "myKultur1"
> > > >
> > > > kultur1.x = 250
> > > >
> > > > kultur1.y = 200
> > > >
> > > > kultur1:scale(1,1)
> > > >
> > > > local function onSport1Tap( self, event )
> > > >
> > > > print(self.id ..  " was tapped." )
> > > >
> > > > end
> > > >
> > > > local function onGossip1Tap( self, event )
> > > >
> > > > print(self.id ..  " was tapped." )
> > > >
> > > > end
> > > >
> > > > local function onKultur1Tap( self, event )
> > > >
> > > > print(self.id ..  " was tapped." )
> > > >
> > > > end
> > > >
> > > > -- TAP addEVENTLISTENER
> > > >
> > > > sport1.tap = onSport1Tap
> > > >
> > > > sport1:addEventListener( "tap", sport1 )
> > > >
> > > > gossip1.tap = onGossip1Tap
> > > >
> > > > gossip1:addEventListener( "tap", gossip1 )
> > > >
> > > > kultur1.tap = onKultur1Tap
> > > >
> > > > kultur1:addEventListener( "tap", kultur1 )

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do the following things:

1. Use this function for tap/touch events:

   ```
   function sport1:touch(e)
       if e.phase == "ended" then
           print(self.id.." was tapped")
       end
   end
   ```
2. Use [tables](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/06/21/understanding-lua-tables-in-corona-sdk/) to create your objects more effectively, especially if you plan on adding more objects.

Here is an example of how:

> local objects = {}
>
> > object[ 1 ] = {id = mySport1, x = 120, y = 90} --by the way, the scale is (1,1) on default
> >
> > object[ 2 ] = {...}
> >
> > object[ 3 ] = {...}

Then one can easily create the information for all of them using [for loops](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/06/21/understanding-lua-tables-in-corona-sdk/):

> for i = 1, #objects do
>
> > local object[i].img = display.newImage("images/"..object[i].id..".png")
> >
> > object[i].img.x, object[i].img.y = object[i].x, object[i].y
> >
> > local shape = object[i].img
> >
> > function shape:touch(e)
> >
> > > if e.phase == "ended" then
> > >
> > > > print(object[i].id.."was tapped")
> > >
> > > end
> > >
> > > shape:addEventListener("touch")
> >
> > end

I hope this was not too advanced... It took me a while to understand the potency of tables, but they become very effective when you have a lot of paramaters or objects needed to be created.
Regarding the touch function, I have not really worked with tap - I just believe touch is *better* and simpler to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will look into your suggestions and try to make it work.
The reason I'm using tap is because it's meant to be used in an interface that should also respond to touch.

Answer (score 0):

just `return true` at the end of all your tap functions, like this:

```
local function onKultur1Tap( self, event )    
  print(self.id .. " was tapped." )
  return  true -- ** just it **
end
```